# Creating a class that can be used with boost::hold_any

Tags: c++, boost

My project is using `boost::hold_any`. While it's okay for existing types, it does not work with custom classes. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost\spirit\home\support\detail\hold_any.hpp>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(){}
    ~Foo(){}

    int Bar;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Foo A;
    boost::spirit::hold_any B(A); // ERROR C2678 HERE
}
```

causes this error

`error C2678: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

I have already tried some overloads but they do not work (declared at class level).

```
std::basic_istream<char>& operator>>(std::basic_istream<char>& is);
std::basic_istream<char> operator>>(std::basic_istream<char> is);
```

How can I create a class that can be used with `boost::hold_any`?

---

**Reply to comment**

Declaring `std::basic_istream<char>& operator>>(std::basic_istream<char>&, Foo&);` at class level causes `error C2804: binary 'operator>>' has too many parameters` and declaring at global scope results in the error `error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const Foo' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

Comment: Are you sure that's the code you're compiling?

Comment: Yes that is the code I'm compiling.

Comment: `boost\spirit\home\support\detail` - it's not in the `boost/spirit/include` public header infrastructure. It's an implementation detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boost::spirit::hold_any` requires, as the error message implies, streaming operators (because it is an undocumented implementation detail of a parser library). In order to use it, you will have to define them for Foo:

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, Foo &dest) {
  // read a Foo from in into dest

  return in;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, Foo const &src) {
  // write src to out

  return out;
}
```

...or you could use the `boost::any` replacement that `boost::spirit::hold_any` was based on that does not have this requirement. It can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11250/High-Performance-Dynamic-Typing-in-C-using-a-Repla). If using `boost::any` really is a problem for you.